# How to install Memgraph on Mac that has M1 processor?

Tags: docker, memgraphdb

I'm confused about what I should do to install Memgraph on Mac that has M1 processor. Do I need to run the command `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform` or should I go to https://memgraph.com/download and download Docker image from that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing Memgraph on Linux, MacOS and Windows can be achieved by using Docker. There is a bit of difference if we talk about **MemgraphDB** and **Memgraph platform**.

If we talk about **MemgraphDB** there is no difference between downloading Memgraph from [download website](https://memgraph.com/download) or pulling from [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/memgraph).
If you want to pull an image and build a container from the Docker hub, it is enough to run the docker command:

```
  docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph
```

This command will pull a MemgraphDB and run the container.

If you use our download page, then you need to load an image first with the following command:

```
docker load -i /path-to/memgraph-<version>-docker.tar.gz
```

After loading an image, you can build and run a container via the following command:

```
docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph
```

If you want to install **Memgraph platform** (MemgraphDB, Lab, mgconsole, Mage), then only option is [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/memgraph/memgraph-platform), and running the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform
```

Previous command will pull the latest image, build the container and run it.
You can find a lot more information on [MacOS installation docs](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/install-memgraph-on-macos-docker)

In addition, there are Linux native packages for Ubuntu, Debian and Centos 7,8.